# Bootstrap - Why does a row shift below first column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Sorry for the lack of descriptive title but I'll hopefully make up for it.

Using a 16 column grid from the cusomizer.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-16 col-sm-2 first-column">Content</div>
            <div class="col-md-14">
              <div class="col-md-16">
                  <div class="row"> <!-- First row
                      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">Content</div>
                      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">Content</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row"> <!-- Problem row
                      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">Content</div>
                      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">Content</div>
                  </div>
```

What happens is that the problem row, when the screen is small/medium, will tuck under the `first-column` column but the first row won't

Any ideas why?

Comment: I needed to set the xs and sm classes on all the columns and it now works

Comment: can you share the complete div for the above problem may be I can try helping you .. Another thing my observation is <div class="col-md-14"> <div class="col-md-16"> can you try putting a row class between <div class="col-md-14"> <div class="row">  <div class="col-md-16">. I need to see the complete div or html..

Comment: I sorted it by my first comment. Problem was when it resized to a small screen, no classes were set telling it what to do